# Combining 3D-text (extruded 2D-font) and a simple solid: RegionProduct produces invalid BoundaryMeshRegion

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, regions

Below is a code fragment demonstrating a problem that has been vexing me for days. The history is in my question [#298513](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298513) (thanks again to @cvgmt and @user21), but knowledge of that question or its answers is not necessary for this question.

**My goal.** I wish to produce, as an STL-exportable region, a marker (a simple hex prism, cylinder, what have you) with a single digit "engraved into" or "scooped out of" the top surface.

**My attempts.** My simplistic approach follows below; note that `RegionDifference` fails with a complaint about a number of lines that apparently have one endpoint not connected to anything (BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl). I find that surprising as the `RegionProduct` that created `regCharOriginal` should not be terribly difficult to compute; besides, `FindMeshDefects` found nothing to complain about.

Following that I tried `RepairMesh` which did improve the situation; the RegionDifference now just remains unevaluated but no longer issues an error message. I presume that is related to the original volume being composed of triangular `Prism`s while the repaired mesh consists of a `Polygon` list (only triangles, apparently).

**My question.** To me this looks like a number of Mathematica bugs; on the other hand, I would find it difficult to exaggerate the degree of my ignorance regarding meshes and the like. So:

Should the code below work, or am I committing some glaring error?
Why does it work for `character="1"` and others that only have an external contour?
Why do some characters with "islands" ("6", "8", "9") work in some fonts?

**Other things.** Working with `ElementMesh` seems to lack the possibility of boolean operations on two such meshes. Am I overlooking something?

Looking into `OpenCascadeLink`, I find that everything I need should be doable, but how do I get from a 2D-surface (or mesh) for a character to a 3D-prism without individually turning each mesh triangle into a prism and then stitching them together in OpenCascade?

Thank you for reading this far. Any pointers, help etc. I will most gratefully receive.

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

regBase=RegionProduct[
  CanonicalizePolygon[RegularPolygon[{11/Sqrt[3.],Pi/6},6]],
  Line[{{0.},{3.}}]
];

(* Output suppressed, would be 3D-image of a hexagonal prism *)

character="0"; (* with "1", the failure does not occur *)
regText2D=BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style[character,Bold,FontSize->8,FontFamily->"Arial"]],_Text];

(* Output suppressed *)

regCharOriginal=RegionProduct[regText2D,Line[{{3.},{2.}}]];

(* Output suppressed, would be a 3D- Region depicting "0" at coords that place it centered into the hex prism and right under the prism's top plane *)

FindMeshDefects[regCharOriginal]

(* No output, apparently the mesh has no discernible defects *)

regAll=RegionDifference[regBase,regCharOriginal]

(* Expected: hex prism with a "0" scooped out of the top *)
(* Actual output: error message, unevaluated RegionDifference *)
(* BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[{{2184,2181},{2175,574},{2227,2215},{652,653},{2552,2553},{2168,2409},{2284,2293},{728,729},{2545,2542},{2230,2180},<<139>>}] only come from a single face. *)
(* BooleanRegion[#1&&!#2&,{«image of hex prism»,«image of "0"»}] *)

regCharRepaired=RepairMesh[regCharOriginal]

(* No output *)

regAll=RegionDifference[regBase,regCharRepaired]

(* Expected: hex prism with a "0" scooped out of the top *)
(* Actual output: unevaluated RegionDifference *)
(* BooleanRegion[#1&&!#2&,{«image of hex prism»,«image of "0"»}] *)
```

Comment: I think it would be good to report this to support AT wolfram.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `OpenCascadeLink` work for such difference computation.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
poly = RegularPolygon[{11/Sqrt[3.], Pi/6}, 6];
regBase = 
  RegionProduct[
   CanonicalizePolygon[RegularPolygon[{11/Sqrt[3.], Pi/6}, 6]], 
   Line[{{0.}, {3.}}]];
character = "0"; 
regText2D = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style[character, Bold, FontSize -> 8, 
     FontFamily -> "Arial"]], _Text];
regCharOriginal = RegionProduct[regText2D, Line[{{3.}, {2.}}]];
```

```
bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[regCharOriginal];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[regBase];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[bm1];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[bm2];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[shape2, shape1];
OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
  shape] // BoundaryMeshRegion
```

[image]

Comment: A different approach would to use `line = RegionBoundary[poly] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> {x, y, 0.};
ocline = OpenCascadeShape[line];
extrudeLine = 
  OpenCascadeShapeLinearSweep[ocline, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}];`. In the next version it will be much easier to convert 2D graphics primitives to OpenCascade shapes. Then we no longer need the `{x_?NumericQ, y_} :> {x, y, 0.}`

Comment: @user21  Good news!

Comment: if you have other use cases that you think would be useful, please let me know. Also, the new code is already available if you want to play with it. https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink

Comment: @cvgmt user21 – Once again, I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: In the next version (or if you get OpenCascadeLink from github) you will be able to directly use the 2D: `ocPoly = OpenCascadeShape[poly]; extrudePoly = OpenCascadeShapeLinearSweep[ocPoly, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}]; ocChar = OpenCascadeShape[regText2D]; ocChar = OpenCascadeShapeTransformation[ocChar, TranslationTransform[{0, 0, 2}]]; extrudeChar = OpenCascadeShapeLinearSweep[ocChar, {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3}}]; shape = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[extrudePoly, extrudeChar];(bmesh =     OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape])["Wireframe"] `